# Is there a way to just show stock on a single product when a user is logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, store, stock

I'm trying to just show stock on a single product when a user is logged in. I've tried manipulating two different scripts I've found, but it's not working. Please help!

```
function show_stock() {
global $product;
if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 3 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remaining">Only ' . number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') . ' left in stock!</div>';
} else {
echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') . ' left in stock</div>'; 
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
add_action( 'init', 'hide_stock_not_logged_in' );

function hide_stock_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       

remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may,

1- Use wp_footer hook, which is called every page load

2- Check if user logged in inside this hook

3- If no, just make "display:none" for css attributes (class or id) of stock item.

Example:

```
function hide_stock_if_user_not_logged_in()
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        echo "<style>p.stock.in-stock { display: none }</style>";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'hide_stock_if_user_not_logged_in' );
```

You may need to change the "style" part. Tested and works fine. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

@MrEbabi 's solution is perfect but as an alternative you could also just use css like so:

```
.logged_in .remaining{
display:none;
}
```